# Keeps returning "TypeError: width() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)" The code works on Python 3 but not on my Python 2.7. What's wrong?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, init

```
class Square(object):

    def __init__(self, height="0", width="0"):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

    @property #This is a getter which allows us to refer to our fields inside of our __init__ method
    def height(self):
        print("Retrieving the height")
        return self.__height #__height: __ to be a private field and protect our data

    @height.setter #This is our setter to prevent us from putting bad data into our Square()
    def height(self, value): #making sure that the value passed in is a digit
        if value.isdigit(): #can use isfloat() for better results, but I'm using isdigit() anyway
            self.__height = value
        else: #if the value is NOT a digit
            print("Please only enter a digit")
    #Now we do the same for our width...
    @property        
    def width(self, value):
        print("Retrieving the width")
        return self.__width

    @width.setter
    def width(self, value):
        if value.isdigit():
            self.__width = value
        else:
            print("Please enter a digit")

    def getArea(self):
        return int(self.__width) * int(self.__height)

def main():
    UserSquare = Square() #My empty square object which I have to define as the user's square (UserSquare)

    height = raw_input("Enter Height : ")
    width = raw_input("Enter Width : ")
    #Now I use the getters (@property) and setters to set everything
    UserSquare.height = height #calling the user Square Object to set the heght
    UserSquare.width = width # calling the user Square Object to set the width

    print("Height :", UserSquare.height)
    print("Height :", UserSquare.width)

    print("Therefore, The area is :", UserSquare.getArea())

main()

#The reason I used getters and setters was so that I can just refer to my height method and width method as height and width
#If I didn't have those getters and setters, I would have to refer to them as height() and width()
```

The program asks the user to input a height and width, and then it calculates and shows the area of their 'square' (actually rectangle)
But it comes up with the TypeError in my title when I enter my width.
Can someone please tell me how I can fix this problem?
I am using PYTHON 2.7

Comment: You actually don't need to pass any parameters for width's getter.

Comment: Your `width` getter has an extra arg, remove `value` arg from the getter. Still fails in Py3: `TypeError: width() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'`

Comment: I assure you that this code does _not_ work in python 3 (as stated in the title), for a multitude of reasons.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand by arg. what do you mean? what piece of code do I have to change to?

Comment: Actually, I got it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
class Square(object):

def __init__(self, height="0", width="0"):
    self.height = height
    self.width = width

@property #This is a getter which allows us to refer to our fields inside of our __init__ method
def height(self):
    print("Retrieving the height")
    return self.__height #__height: __ to be a private field and protect our data

@height.setter #This is our setter to prevent us from putting bad data into our Square()
def height(self, value): #making sure that the value passed in is a digit
    if value.isdigit(): #can use isfloat() for better results, but I'm using isdigit() anyway
        self.__height = value
    else: #if the value is NOT a digit
        print("Please only enter a digit")
#Now we do the same for our width...
@property        
def width(self):
    print("Retrieving the width")
    return self.__width

@width.setter
def width(self, value):
    if value.isdigit():
        self.__width = value
    else:
        print("Please enter a digit")

def getArea(self):
    return int(self.__width) * int(self.__height)

def main():
    UserSquare = Square() #My empty square object which I have to define as the user's square (UserSquare)

height = raw_input("Enter Height : ")
width = raw_input("Enter Width : ")
#Now I use the getters (@property) and setters to set everything
UserSquare.height = height #calling the user Square Object to set the heght
UserSquare.width = width # calling the user Square Object to set the width

print("Height :", UserSquare.height)
print("Height :", UserSquare.width)

print("Therefore, The area is :", UserSquare.getArea())

main()
```

I had to make my def width(self, value) into def width under @property.
thanks everyone